# Utilizing iPhone's Gyroscope Values to Control HTML elements

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, gyroscope

What I'm trying to achieve here is to read the y-axis values of the gyroscope and use that to control the CSS of some images in HTML.

So my HTML/CSS looks something like the following:

```
<style>
    .imgblock{
         display:none;
    }
</style>

<div id="images">
   <img id="img01" class="imgblock" src="images/img01.jpg"/>
   <img id="img02" class="imgblock" src="images/img02.jpg"/>
   <img id="img03" class="imgblock" src="images/img03.jpg"/>
   <img id="img04" class="imgblock" src="images/img04.jpg"/>
   <img id="img05" class="imgblock" src="images/img05.jpg"/>
</div>
```

So what's supposed to happen here is that when I tilt the iPhone to -45 degrees along the y-axis (towards the left), it is suppose to set the `display:block` to `<img id="img01" class="imgblock" src="images/img01.jpg"/>` and `display:none` to the rest of the images. And if I tilt it towards the right a little such that the orientation is now -27 degrees along the y-axis, `display:block` will be set to `<img id="img02" class="imgblock" src="images/img02.jpg"/>` and `display:none` will be set to the rest of the images.

I have done some research into this and stumbled a brilliant article [here](http://www.peterfriese.de/how-to-use-the-gyroscope-of-your-iphone-in-a-mobile-web-app/) but am not too sure how to implement the codes into mine. I have tried implementing it this way but it isn't working:

```
window.ondeviceorientation = function(event) {
    gamma = Math.round(event.gamma);    
    gamma = Math.round(event.beta); 
    if (gamma = -45){
        $("#img01").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#img02, #img03, #img04, #img05").css({"display":"none"})
    } elseif (gamma = -27) {
        $("#img02").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#img01, #img03, #img04, #img05").css({"display":"none"})
    }
}
```

I'm pretty certain that I messed badly somewhere above. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're overwriting your gamma value with beta in the second line of your event handler:

```
gamma = Math.round(event.beta);
```